# Calling a function of another translation unit can cause static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++, c++03, static-order-fiasco

a.cpp

```
static Foo fooobj;
void Usefoo()
{
    foooobj.somefunc();
}
```

b.cpp

```
static Bar barobj;
```

and here is the constructor of `Bar`

```
 Bar::Bar()
 {
     Usefoo();
 }
```

Will this lead to static initialization order fiasco?
If yes, how can I solve it. I thought of something like below:

```
Foo* GetFoo*()
{
    static Foo *fooobj = new Foo();
    return fooobj;
}
```

But since I don't have support of C++11, static local initialization is not thread safe.
Hence this cannot work.

Also what if `barobj` was non-static. Then I don't have to worry about this fiasco right? For a non-static object initialization which is depending on another non-static object initialization in a different translation unit is not an issue. Right?

Comment: Does `Bar` depend of `Foo`?

Comment: @Jarod42 No. But `Bar`'s constructor calls `Usefoo()` which internally uses global `fooobj`. My concern is can I be sure that `fooobj` will be completely initialized when I enter `UseFoo`.

Comment: Wait a minute, do you intend to call `GetFoo` with multiple threads unsynchronized? Why do the classes have to be static?

Comment: Do you rely on thread safety at all?

Comment: If you have multiple threads, a pretty simple way to get the singletons initialised correctly would be simply calling the getters once in correct order *before* creating multiple threads, e. g. in `main`.

Comment: @Superlokkus Yes. That is why I cannot use `GetFoo()` to solve this problem.

Comment: Off-topic: `Foo& getFoo() { static Foo instance; return instance; }` usually is superior singleton pattern, as it would assure that Foo's destructor is called when programme terminates (if you insist on pointer as return value, `Foo* getFoo() { static Foo instance; return &instance; }` is fine as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua But I cannot guarantee thread safety of `FetGoo()` and static initialization for local variables is not thread safe.

Comment: @user3819404 That's why that comment was prefaced with "off-topic". (But I initially missed that too.)

Comment: Here you can read how to implement singletons thread safe
https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-6-double-checked-locking.html

Comment: `Bar& getBar(); Foo& getFoo(); int main() { getFoo(); getBar(); std::thread t1(...); std::thread t2(...); /* ... */ return 0; }` and you shouldn't have problems any more. Actually, as getBar would use getFoo anyway, you wouldn't even have to call the latter, still I'd do for consistency.

Comment: GCC offers an attribute [`init_priority`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) with which you could control initialisation order as well. Be aware, though, that this is a *non-portable* solution!!!

Comment: @Aconcagua Ooooh TIL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this lead to static initialization order fiasco?

Yes.

> I thought of something like below:

Usually you'd avoid the pointers and do a nice:

```
Foo& GetFoo()
{
    static Foo fooobj;
    return fooobj;
}
```

> But since I don't have support of C++11, static local initialization is not thread safe.

Okay, still problematic then.

> Also what if barobj was non-static. Then I don't have to worry about this fiasco right?

Right. You should avoid these globals. In fact, this is a pretty good example of why we try to avoid globals.

Encapsulate your state into a nice class, perhaps instantiated in `main` and passed around as needed, instead.

> For a non-static object initialization which is depending on another non-static object initialization in a different translation unit is not an issue. Right?

Right. I can't think of a way to break that unless your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: For the last part, If there is a global non-static `Bar obj` in `bar.cpp` depending on a global non-static `Foo obj` in `foo.cpp` it should not cause any problems?

Comment: @user3819404 Sorry, not sure what you mean by "global non-static". All globals have static storage duration. The `static` keyword there means "internal linkage". Yes, it's dumb :)

Comment: So my objects are global. So I have a problem. Right?

Comment: @user3819404 Exactly. Just removing the `static` keyword from the variable doesn't change anything about the issue. Confusion arises because one and the same word ('static') is used with two different (context-dependent) meanings...

Comment: @user3819404 Right.

Comment: @Aconcagua There is a third ;)

Comment: I understand that the requirements are rigid, but is it possible to have a solution for this scenario taking all the constraints into consideration(like non C++11 support and global variables)>

Comment: @user3819404 I've already answered the question; asking it again won't change the answer. :)